# Shell script to adjust filenames (from the end)

Tags: shell, filenames

I am running into a problem as how to do a BATCH adjustment for changing filenames.

All my files look like this:

1602017EN.MPG
1802312EN.MPG
etc.

I need to change 2 thing for all filenames.

I need to adjust the file extension to lowercase, so it reads .mpg instead of .MPG.
For this part, i am using an apple automator service. This works perfectly.

Second, i need to remove the last 2 characters, the letters.

So the first item would read 1602017.mpg and so on.

It would be perfect if it can be done with a shell script that i can add to my automator service, so it makes change no1 and no2 after each other.

Thank you VERY much in advance!

Comment: Do you want a Unix shell script or a Windows batch file? You used both tags.

Comment: @Barmar: Good question, but the mention of Apple Automator strongly suggests that Windows is not relevant (so I removed the 'batch-file' tag).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, it was more for the OP's benefit, to let him know that these things are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Sorry i meant batch as in 'make it work for a bunch of files'. Not as in Windows...bleg ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `bash` for shell scripting, you could do it easily using `sed`:

```
for file in "$@"
do
    name=$(echo "$file" | sed 's/[A-Z][A-Z].MPG$/.mpg/')
    mv "$file" "$name"
done
```

(working on the reasonable looking assumption that there are no newlines in the file names).

However, you can also do it directly in `bash` without invoking an external program:

```
$ for file in 1602017EN.MPG 1802312EN.MPG; do echo ${file/[A-Z][A-Z].MPG/.mpg}; done
1602017.mpg
1802312.mpg
$
```

Comment: Note that `"$@"` is the default for `for`.

Comment: Yeah. I know.  I don't care; I prefer to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks for your Quick reply! 
Do these commando's adjust ALL files in the current directory? Cause there are also some .pdf and other files, i dont want to touch those..

Comment: I think i just fixed that myself by changing the first line into 

for file in *.MPG

Comment: The first version works on the file names it is given on the command line.  You can change the `"$@"` into `*.MPG` or just invoke the script as `convert_script *.MPG`.  Personally, I seldom write a script that has the file names to work on hard-wired into it; I expect the names to be given as arguments to the script.